# Running program: console of Linux kernel image (Android) vs Android APK

Tags: android

I'm very new with Android. Now I have a project about driver and library (C/C++) of a device on Android. I can boot the device up with Android, and also can boot it up with only the Linux kernel image in Android package.

While the library can be reuse from the same product on Linux and the driver has already configured for new board on Android, I really don't care about implementing Android application APK to test both library and driver. I also don't care about ADB connection. I just want to use the same application (console) from Linux project and rebuild it for Android by NDK for testing.

My question is that if there is any different between running a program on console (after booting only Linux kernel image) and running it on GUI of Android (in top of a bunch of Android library/framework). Everything I know up to now is to create a Android APK and use JNI to call library. I don't know if there is any chance for a code that worked well on just-kernel-image will be failed on Android-whole-system.

Comment: You can try to run it from the adb shell, or from a local shell of a terminal emulator such as connectbot.  If you were able to build against android libraries, the next problem you might face would be insufficient linux permissions.

Comment: Thank you. Because I had some wrong steps when building kernel image and Android BSP, I realize that I can get the Linux console via UART and don't know that is actually Android platform or Linux platform. Then if I run the program on that console, can I say I checked my code on Android? I think it's better to create an Android APK and run it from the top of Android. But there are some guys just use the Linux kernel image came with the Android BSP and say that their code were checked on Android. If so, from the kernel side up to library layer, not much different between Android and Linux.

Comment: The major concerns would be that android uses its own C library - bionic - which is not traditional for an embedded linux.  And then that 3rd party applications will not have permission to access resources which you have not explicitly exposed.  Ultimately you must test in a way which corresponds to intended usage.  Consider linking your test code as a jni library and changing usage of stdout/stderr to calls to Android native logging, or to a pipe which you can display from the android java side.